# PIMCORE: How to globally configure TinyMCE (WYSIWYG) for data object? (Version 11.1.4)

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, pimcore

The only thing which is documented is how to configure [EDITABLE WYSIWYG](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Documents/Editables/WYSIWYG/). But not how to configure DATA OBJECT WYSIWYG.